# How to get child nodes for parent model with rabl output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I am building a Rails 3 web app and I am using Rabl for JSON output.
In my app I got the following tables:

Account
 - Can have one or many clients
 - Can have one or many projects

Clients
 - Belongs to an account

Project
 - Belongs to an account

When I fetch a single project I need to get an array of all clients that belongs to the current account along with the project data. How can I do this using Rabl?